# How to pass data from containing app to widget in today view?

Tags: ios, performance, ios8, widget

I recently wrote a widget app, and according to some articles, I used "App Group" as the bridge to pass my data from my containing app to widget app, there are not only some images and words info, but also the frame/layout info in my data.

The problem is that sometimes I found my widget view was not shown up immediately, which may existed a 1~3 seconds delay. What's worse, my widget view showed "Unable to download" if the data included too many info(I need show many things in my widget).

After a long attempt, I still not found the real reason which caused the issues. So now I guess the "App Group" may not work so well, can someone help me figure out what's wrong with my work?